# Best approach to moderate posts in express nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a project in NodeJS, Mongodb, ExpressJS and at this time I would like to be able to moderate each post someone posts and therefore I am kindly asking what would best approach be to do so ?

I would have some users as Moderators and they would need to approve/moderate each post before the post is being released for public.

The same post could be seen only by the post creator during the time it's under review.

What would the best approach be to do something like this ?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create post schema in mongoose

Keep a field in the schema, say

```
curated: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
```

This field would determine whether a post is curated and should be visible to the public, or not

Initially, curated = false

Create a front-end panel for the moderators to view the posts.

While querying in the MongoDB for the list of posts to be shown,
add appropriate filter, so that the post is visible only if the user is the creator of post or if his role is, let's say "moderator"

req.user is the current user.
Let's say req.user = {roles:["user", "moderator", "admin"]};

```
if(req.user.roles.indexOf("moderator")>-1){
  db.getCollection("posts").find({user: req.user})
}
```

This will only return posts which have been created by the current user, or if the current user is a moderator

Now the user can choose to change post.curated to true, and update the post

Now, while fetching for the list of posts to be visible to public, add filter

```
db.getCollection("posts").find({curated:true})
```

Comment: Ask me anything, if you need more help :)

Comment: Shreya thank you for your information, I was thinking something similar, but not as simple as you :)
I will come to this part in a week or so, if I have any other questions I will post it here :) thank you once again !  I really appreciate it